# Find all indices of duplicates and write them in new columns

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data.frame with a single column, a vector of strings.

These strings have duplicate values. 
I want to find the character strings that have duplicates in this vector and write their index of position in a new column.

So for example consider I have:

```
DT<- data.frame(string=A,B,C,D,E,F,A,C,F,Z,A)
```

I want to get:

```
string match2 match2 match3 matchx....
A      1       7      11
B      2       NA     NA
C      3       8      NA
D      4       NA     NA
E      5       NA     NA
F      6       9      NA
A      1       7      11
C      3       8      NA
F      6       9      NA
Z      10      NA     NA
A      1       7      11
```

The string is ways longer than in this example and I do not know the amount of maximum columns I need.

What will be the most effective way to do this? 
I know that there is the duplicate function but I am not exactly sure how to combine it to the result I want to get here.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `data.table`.  After grouping by 'string', get the sequence (`seq_len(.N)`) and row index (`.I`), then `dcast` to 'wide' format and join with the original dataset `on` the 'string'

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(DT)[, .(seq_len(.N),.I), string],string ~ paste0("match", V1))[DT, on = "string"]
#     string match1 match2 match3
# 1:      A      1      7     11
# 2:      B      2     NA     NA
# 3:      C      3      8     NA
# 4:      D      4     NA     NA
# 5:      E      5     NA     NA
# 6:      F      6      9     NA
# 7:      A      1      7     11
# 8:      C      3      8     NA
# 9:      F      6      9     NA
#10:      Z     10     NA     NA
#11:      A      1      7     11
```

---

Or another option would be to `split` the sequence of rows with 'string', pad the `list` elements with `NA` for length that are less, and `merge` with the original dataset (using `base R` methods)

```
lst <- split(seq_len(nrow(DT)), DT$string)
merge(DT, do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst)))),
               by.x = "string", by.y = "row.names")
```

#### data

```
DT<- data.frame(string=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","C",
              "F","Z","A"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you all!! All answers are great, and solved my problem completely. I take this one as the accepted one as it is the shortest one and naming of columns is included.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way of doing this. I'm sure a data.table one liner follows.

```
DT<- data.frame(string=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","A","C","F","Z","A"))

# find matches
rbf <- sapply(DT$string, FUN = function(x, DT) which(DT %in% x), DT = DT$string)

# fill in NAs to have a pretty matrix
out <- sapply(rbf, FUN = function(x, mx) c(x, rep(NA, length.out = mx - length(x))), max(sapply(rbf, length)))

# bind it to the original data
cbind(DT, t(out))

   string  1  2  3
1       A  1  7 11
2       B  2 NA NA
3       C  3  8 NA
4       D  4 NA NA
5       E  5 NA NA
6       F  6  9 NA
7       A  1  7 11
8       C  3  8 NA
9       F  6  9 NA
10      Z 10 NA NA
11      A  1  7 11
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's one that uses `tidyverse` tools ( not quite a one-liner ;) ):

```
library( tidyverse )

DT %>% group_by( string ) %>%
  do( idx = which(DT$string == unique(.$string)) ) %>% 
  ungroup %>% unnest %>% group_by( string ) %>%
  mutate( m = stringr::str_c( "match", 1:n() ) ) %>%
  spread( m, idx )
```